# How to combine AsyncTask of my database with google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

I have a map which will show the places nearby after the button is clicked.Then, I have customized my marker by using google map utils.For example:

```
icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(Here would be the data from database)))
```

So,the marker will show the data inside it.The problem is before AsynTask implement in my project everything is worked properly and the marker will show the place's name by default,it will be like this:

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(place.getName().toString())))
```

After the AsynTask in my project, it stop working and even the marker wouldn't displayed after the button is clicked.The full coding will be like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener, View.OnClickListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private Button btnFindNearby;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
private Location currentLocation;
private static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 500;
private Map<Marker, Result> places = new HashMap<>();
//Json url to get the place's name varaible to json
private static final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.1.2/dataconnection.php";
String myJSON;
private JSONArray users = null;
private static final String JSON_ARRAY ="result";
private static final String name = "name";
private static final String description = "description";
private static final String title = "title";
private String JSName;
private String JSDesc;
private String JSTitle;
private String Jname;
private String Jtitle;
Private String iconTitle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.map));
    initializeViews();
}

private void initializeViews() {
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    btnFindNearby = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_findNearby);
    btnFindNearby.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}

private void addMarker(Result place,String Jname.String Jtitle) {
    com.mkpazon.foodnearby.net.Location location =           place.getGeometry().getLocation();
    IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
    double latitude = location.getLat();
    double longitude = location.getLng();
if(Jname.equals(place.getName().toString()))
{
      iconTitle=Jtitle;
}else{
     iconTitle=place.getName().toString();
}
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(iconTitle)))
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title(place.getName())
            .anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV())
            .snippet(place.getVicinity()));
    places.put(marker, place);


}

private void clearMarkers() {
    for (Marker marker : places.keySet()) {
        //Remove marker from map
        marker.remove();
    }
    places.clear();
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    this.currentLocation = location;
    //zoom  the map automatically
    float zoomLevel = (float) 16.0; //This goes up to 21
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnFindNearby) {
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            List<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
            types.add("food");
            types.add("cafe");
            types.add("restaurant");
            getJSON(JSON_URL);
            PlacesUtility.findPlacesWithinRadius(this, types, currentLocation, DEFAULT_RADIUS, new PlacesSearchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(SearchResponse response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Clearing all markers");
                    clearMarkers();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Adding result markers");
                    List<Result> results = response.getResults();


                    for (Result result : results) {
                      for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                        try {
                            JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSName = c.getString(name);
                            JSDesc = c.getString(description);
                            JSTitle = c.getString(title);
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        com.mkpazon.foodnearby.net.Location location = result.getGeometry().getLocation();
                        double latitude = location.getLat();
                        double longitude = location.getLng();
                        Log.d(TAG, "> " + result.getName() + " " + latitude + "," + longitude);
                        addMarker(result,JSName,JSTitle);

                    }
                }
                     }
            });

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current location not available");
            final Dialog dialog = InfoDialog.newInstance(this, getString(R.string.error),
                    getString(R.string.current_location_not_available), null);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}//end of find button

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Info window of marker \"" + marker.getTitle() + "\" has been clicked.");
    Result place = places.get(marker);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String placeJson = gson.toJson(place);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlaceDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PlaceDetailsActivity.EXTRA_PLACE_JSON, placeJson);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//Async Task to access the web
private void getJSON(String url) {
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String result = null;
        //ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait...",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String uri = params[0];

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");
                }
                result=sb.toString().trim();
                return sb.toString().trim();

            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            myJSON=result;
            extractJSON(myJSON);
            //loading.dismiss();
            //textViewJSON.setText(s);

        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute(url);
}

//Extrta JSON
public void extractJSON(String myJSONString)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
  }
```

Plz help to me find the solution to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AsyncTask runs inside another thread, so it's asynchronous.

The code where you use **PlacesUtility.findPlacesWithinRadius** should be executed when the AsyncTask finishes, not in parallel. So you had to move the **PlacesUtility.findPlacesWithinRadius** (only this) to **onPostExecute** from your AsyncTask.

Moving the code should solve your problem.

Comment: Meant that I have to move `public void onClick(VIew v){ //code };` to onPostExecute?

Comment: after few minutes struggle with the code, it's work!BTW,thx @user5554570

Comment: Hi @jvretamero I have a similar problem with google maps. Can you take a look, please?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553554/my-ui-is-blocked-using-asynctask-with-distancematrix-and-google-maps